# Where to add new objects in rails - should they go in the models folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, controller

I come from a Java background, and am very used to wrapping code into objects.

I was working on my first rails application; while writing up the controller, I wanted to wrap a snippet of code that adapted input from the view and modified it to a format that is accepted by the backend.

I was unsure on where to position these objects. Should this "Adaptor" object I created go into the models? (I tried putting it there, but I cannot manage to find a reference to the file using "require".)

Thanks!

**EDIT**

For example, say my input was a date in a string format: "31st July" -> my controller would be:

```
def create
  adaptor = Adaptor.new
  date = adaptor.to_date(params[:date])
  ...
end
```

Where would the adaptor live? And if this object were to be "common" code, could it be used by my models?

Comment: When you say object, can you clarify a bit more?  In Ruby, everything is essentially an object, but I get the impression you may mean a new class/module or perhaps a few methods...

Comment: And, is this adaptor something you will use for a single model, or might it be used across others?

Comment: yes, I mean class/module. This adaptor will be used for various controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is presumably a helper object, and should then go into the helpers folder. It is also possible that this should be part of the model. You should read a bit about the "**Fat Model, skinny controller**" strategy.

A quick google brought these up:

[devinterface.com](http://blog.devinterface.com/2010/06/rails-best-practices-1-fat-model-skinny-controller/)

[goodcoresoft.com](http://blog.goodcoresoft.com/rails-best-practice-fat-model-skinny-controller/)

Comment: I did want to make a skinny controller, hence I did not want to add all my adapting code into the controller. For example, if my input were to be "31st of July", my adaptor would convert it to a Date object. -> adaptor.to_date(params[:date]) - and hence the controller would have only one line of conversion - keeping it as skinny :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer. This sounds like it should be a helper method. Helpers are basically methods you can reuse between more than one controller. What you are describing sounds like it is a helper, and thus should be stored in the Helpers folder.